# How to find the sum $\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{(k+1)\sqrt{k}+k\sqrt{(k+1)}}$?

Tags: summation

How do you find the sum $$\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{(k+1)\sqrt{k}+k\sqrt{(k+1)}}?$$ Sorry for not provide any of my idea since I have no idea about what to do.

I hope everyone here could help me. Thank you

Comment: Are there parentheses somewhere? Is the first $\sqrt k$ in the numerator or denominator?  To get square root signs in MathJax use \sqrt and put the argument in braces to get it under the square root sign.  You could get a good approximation from converting it to an integral.

Comment: I edited the expression to make it more readable, please tell me if this is correct.

Comment: If it _is_ correct - try rationalising the denominator term-by-term by multiplying and dividing by $(k+1)\sqrt{k} - k\sqrt{(k+1)}$. You end up with a telescoping sum.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 yes it is correct. Sorry for my trouble

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the comments, we have that

$$ \frac{1}{(k+1)\sqrt{k}+k\sqrt{(k+1)}}\cdot \frac{(k+1)\sqrt{k}-k\sqrt{(k+1)}}{(k+1)\sqrt{k}-k\sqrt{(k+1)}}= \frac{(k+1)\sqrt{k}-k\sqrt{(k+1)}}{k^2+k}=$$

$$=\frac{\sqrt{k}}{k}-\frac{\sqrt{k+1}}{k+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$$

and we obtain a telescoping sum.

Comment: Or even simpler, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$.

Comment: @J.G. Yes that's fine. I add also that step.